# Why is this Flash drive apparently nearly full?

Tags: usb-drive, rsync

I have several 16GB Flash drives that I use for backups. Some of them are `Master Boot Record` and `ext4`. Some are `not bootable` and `ext4`. It does not seem to make any difference to my need for file storage.

The backup files are in ~/Backups and they are typically about 3GB. I will typically have 3 such files for a total of 9GB, because I have a script that deletes the oldest if there are more than 3 files present in ~/Backups. The ~/Backups used to be on a 1TB hard disk but more recently on a 240GB SSD.

This is the backup command.

```
rsync --compress --dirs --delete --times --perms --owner --group 
--progress ~/Backups/ /media/brian/Flash
```

Since I have several Flash drives and I cycle through them in a regular way, by the time I get around to re-using a Flash drive, all of its files will be old, so the synch involves deleting 3 files and writing 3 files. Sometimes I have problems where the synch fails in some way, so I simply repeat until it works. Usually I don't pay much attention to why it fails because the `rsync` failure message is usually cryptic and retrying almost always works and if I reboot Ubuntu it has a better chance of working. Sometimes I reformat the Flash drive and the synch will succeed but I don't know if the retry alone would have succeeded or if rebooting Ubuntu is the reason it succeeded.  The unreliability is puzzling but the success of retries is more puzzling. The synch will fail about 20% of the time. The Flash drives range from new to about 3 years old. I would not say that the older ones are less reliable than the new ones because it is hard to discern that without keeping detailed statistics. I've not yet had to trash a Flash drive because retries, reformatting, and rebooting eventually do make it work.

Today it failed because of a lack of space and I think the error message told me it was lacking space. This does not make sense because I only want to store 3 files of 3GB each in a 16GB device. This image shows the device is almost full but there are only 2 files occupying 6GB.

[image: Image of the Flash drive "properties"]

How is this possible? Here's the output of `ls`.

[image: Directory listing of the Flash drive]

Edit: I have been asked to unmount and `fsck`. The unmount happens on the second line of this screenshot.

[image: Errors were found.]

Comment: Run a filesystem check. Unmount the drive and do `sudo fsck /dev/sd??`, with the correct identifier (find out with e.g `lsblk`)

Comment: How do you want me to unmount it? We should probably use the command line to be sure of what is going on.

Comment: Unmount with `umount /media/brian/Flash`. To perform the FS check, note that the drive can also be identified as `/dev/disk/by-label/Flash`

Comment: Results from unmount and `fsck` will be added to the post.

Comment: There were apparently filesystem errors that were corrected. Did this fix the usage mismatch?

Comment: I don't know how to answer the prompts in order to fix the Flash drive. I will simply use a GUI tool like "Disks" to reformat. The follow up question will be: why are Flash drives so unreliable? `rsync` on 9GB to a set of Flash drives seems to have about a 20% failure rate that may force a retry of `rsync` or reformat.

Comment: Do that, but please make sure to do a bad sector scan when creating the filesystem. I don't know if "Disks" offers this. Otherwise do it from the command line `sudo mke2fs -t ext4 -L "Flash" -vcc /dev/sdb1` __Make sure the flashdrive is really /dev/sdb!__